# Web sraping script to download subtitles from a particular site

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to use Python and any of the relevant libraries for web scraping to automatically download the English subtitles of the movies or TV shows I specify in a list of subtitles to download.

The list can contain the name of the movie or TV show. I understand a possible problem could be that TV shows usually have many episodes and many seasons. If it is possible to download the subtitles for all of the episodes in all the seasons, then I'd like that. If not, I would appreciate any hints as to some possible solution.

I have tried with the following script. This is just my first attempt. I'm aware of the fact that this is very simplistic and has some basic problems but I'd like to learn how to do this properly.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the OpenSubtitles website
url = "https://english-subtitles.org"

# List of movies/shows
movies = ["Babylon Berlin"]

# Loop through each movie/show
for movie in movies:
    # Build the URL for the movie/show
    movie_url = url + "?q=" + movie
    
    # Request the URL
    response = requests.get(movie_url)

    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find the download link
    download_link = soup.find('a', {'class': 'download-subtitle'})['href']


    # Download the subtitle file
    subtitle_file = requests.get(download_link, allow_redirects=True)

# Save the file
    open('subtitle_file.srt', 'wb').write(subtitle_file.content)
```

This is one particular example. I have also tried with different titles for TV shows or movies in the following sites:

```
https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/subs
https://english-subtitles.org
https://yts-subs.com
```

In all cases I'm getting the error:

```
    download_link = soup.find('a', {'class': 'download-subtitle'})['href']
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This suggests something that was obvious to me from the very beginning, which is that just having a string with the title of the movie I want the subtitles for is going to be problematic because every site is going to have specific naming conventions for the links to the .srt files (sometimes contained in a zip) that are the target of the downloading.

I don't know how to solve this problem, though. My intuition is that the solution would involve using some regular expression that would match all of the relevant links but I have no idea as to how this would be implemented.

Can anybody suggest an alternative solution to accomplish this goal? As I said, this is just my first attempt using information from tutorials I found googling. Perhaps there are other Python libraries that might be better? Perhaps the solution would involve looking for the particular json, xml or .sqlite file where the site stores the databases of its contents?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code downloads all episodes from pages provided in `urls_of_pages`. If you need to download more season from `wtfdetective.com`, put more urls into the variable.

You proabbly want to use `soup.find_all` rather than `soup.find` to find urls of all episodes. I used regular expression to find urls that match format `download/<some digits>`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# URL of https://wtfdetective.com/babylon-berlin-season-4-subtitles-english-srt/ website
urls_of_pages = ["https://wtfdetective.com/babylon-berlin-season-4-subtitles-english-srt/"]

for page_url in urls_of_pages:
    response = requests.get(page_url)

    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find the download link of all episodes,
    # make sure you provided href kwarg to this function
    # to select only tags that have href attribute
    episodes = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"download/\d+"))
        
    for item in episodes:
        # get url of item
        link = item["href"]
        # normalize episode name
        name = item.text.lower().replace(" ", "_")

        print(f"Downloading {name} from {link} url ...")

        # Download the subtitle file
        subtitle_file = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)
        
        # Save the file
        with open(f"{name}.srt", 'wb') as file:
            file.write(subtitle_file.content)
```

Comment: OK, thank you so much @Jurakin. I edited my question to eliminate the confusion I introduced. Your code works but I'd like to learn a bit more about how to do this in a more general situation. Your script finds the links containing the string 'download' in the URL I used in the example. In the default situation, however, I don't know the specific URL for the page that contains all the links to the files I want. All I know is that I want to download the English subtitles for a particular show. How would I do that? Check the edited original question.

Comment: I think all that would need to be added to your script are some lines of code that use the search functionality in the given site to find the page containing the download links, right?

Comment: @jfontana I see you've edited the link to `english-subtitles.org`. It's not so easy to scrape the `english-subtitles.org` download link due to cloudflare protection (if you really want to scrape it, we recommend using [selenium4](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to do so). I think you might want to use this project [python-opensubtitles](https://github.com/agonzalezro/python-opensubtitles) to access the `opensubtitles` api.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jurakin! Yes, I saw that answer and I commented there. Pity because I liked the simplicity and efficiency of the script you provided here. I have no clue as to how to start with your suggestion as I'm totally new to selenium (let alone s4). The python library looks very interesting. Do the two work in tandem? That is, you make Selenium4 do certain things and opensubtitles others like when using BeautifulSoup and Selenium together?

Comment: @jfontana  You can use selenium to get the source code and put it in a beautiful soup. But why would you do that? Selenium can do the same thing (and better). So if you must, use selenium (the page loads content via javascript or has antibot services), otherwise use beautiful soup (it's faster and simplier). Can you please accept my answer if it helped you and I can get a score? That's just how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Sorry @Jurakin. Since my attention moved to the solution with Selenium afterwards, I completely forgot about this one. Answer accepted and appreciated!